# How to use path mapping with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm moving forward with the project and I want to start writing tests.

But I came across a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I'm using path mapping in the project, but when I write the tests the page (or component) is not found.

I care like this

`import Dashboard from '@pages/dashboard';`

and the error is

`Cannot find module '@pages/dashboard' from 'src/__tests__/pages/dashboard.test.tsx'`

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

After taking another look at the Jest documentation I realized that the `jest.config.ts` settings were wrong.

I changed it to this and it worked.

`moduleNameMapper: { '^@pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages/$1' }`

Just for the record, my `tsconfig` looks like this:

`"paths": { "@pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"] }`